# how to set time of web service in windows phone

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

i have a web service.

it takes 10-15 seconds to upload completely. But some time due to slow internet connection it takes more than 15 second.

I want to open a message box or pop up box which open when the service takes more than 15 seconds, to display message "Slow Internet Connection".

How can  i add timer in my code so that a pop up block open(Or alert says Slow Connection) on page load event when web service takes time more than 15 second to load ?

Please help me on this...

public Quiz()

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatchTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        int serviceCount = 15;
        Loaded += Quiz_Loaded;
    }

    protected void Quiz_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Loading Questions...";
        pg2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        txtloading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        if (!timer.IsEnabled)
        {
           timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
           timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
           timer.Start();
        }
    }
     void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
       serviceCount--;
       if (serviceCount < 15)
       {
        PostData();
       }
       else
       {
           txtloading.Text = "slow connection.....";
       }
    }

    private void PostData()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("my web service url");
        string data = "device_id=test123&quiz_type=all";
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.UploadStringAsync(uri, data);
        wc.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadComplete;
    }
    public void wc_UploadComplete(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        question = rootObject.questions;
        DisplayQuestion();
        SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
        pg2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        txtloading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

i want to call message block when web service takes time more than 15 second. & also have a retry button which reload the page again to get all data from service..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that is initialized whenever the first call to the web service is initiated. That way, whenever a given timespan elapses, you can trigger a custom action (such as a notification).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I already used Dispatch Timer but not get any success. If you please provide sample code for this, it would be great help for me...

Comment: Where are you using DispatcherTimer? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Sorry i haven't paste my utility page where i was testing timer. I edit my question please check it & tell my mistake